# I seem to have some phantom reputation

Tags: bug, reputation

This is pretty innocuous, and I'm more asking out of curiosity, but I [seem to have](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/113/year/judaism) more reputation for the year than I have reputation total.  Specifically at the time of this posting, 6012 total and 6032 for the year.

Month-by-month, I gained 15 reputation for the year over my total [in January](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/113/month/judaism/2014-01-01), 3 more [in February](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/113/month/judaism/2014-02-02), and 2 more [in March](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/113/month/judaism/2014-02-02).

Comment: Also, you joined this site this year (in 2014), so there are no weird boundary cases around Jan 1.

Comment: I'm guessing deleted posts are to blame somehow

Comment: sabbahillel has the same "problem".

Comment: I'm looking into this.

Comment: @TimPost See answer.

Comment: @TimPost [meta-tag:status-bydesign]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141628/why-is-my-total-reputation-less-than-my-monthly-reputation) - downvotes and deleted posts are not counted in your monthly (and I assume yearly) score, but are factored in to the displayed total score.