# My unjustly acquired reputation

Tags: discussion, status-norepro, reputation, deleted-answers

I recently deleted an answer that I had posted.
The answer had attracted one downvote and one upvote. (Net effect on my rep. +8).

One of the comments clearly demonstrated that the answer was wrong.

I feel that the 8 were unjustly acquired.

Does/should the system take account of this?

This question is highly related the answer to [this question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/i-seem-to-have-some-phantom-reputation/2054#2054) on phantom reputation.

Comment: [Here's something on the topic from a Stack Exchange employee.](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/216854) A quotation therefrom partially answers your question "Does... the system take account of this?": "the system strives to both limit the amount of deletions that can be performed at one time and automatically notifies the moderator team" if there were many deletions by a single author.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. I'm pretty sure that the 8 points should disappear when you delete a post like that. Did they?

Comment: Note that rep score totals probably lag behind the events that affect them.

Comment: Rep is a rough indication of how well you know your way around the system. You have 18,512. 8 points one way or t'other is irrelevant. But you can check by viewing your rep history at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation.

Comment: @Shokhet Apologies. When checking the reputation, I find no record of the occurrences I referred to. So the question is not a question.

Comment: Oh, and I misread the question as "I got eight rep points for deleting an answer of mine". Ignore my preceding comment.